# React leaflet creates a new marker point and then adds the popup on that point

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

I have a react-leaflet application that renders a map with a ClusterGroup. The map is rendered correctly with the points but when I try to click on the point in the map to show a popup for the associated properties, a new point is created and then the new point on the map has those properties.
The data for the GeoJSON component (geoUnits) is passed in as props

Attached is the following code

SimpleMap.tsx

```
import { LatLngExpression } from 'leaflet';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useMap } from './hooks';
import GeoJSONLayer from './components/GeoJsonLayer';
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import MenuOverlay from './components/MenuOverlay';
import Drawing from './Drawing';
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-cluster';
import GeoJSONUnitLayer from './components/GeoJsonLayer/GeoJSONUnitLayer';
import GeoJSONPoisLayer from './components/GeoJsonLayer/GeoJSONPoisLayer';

export const SimpleMap = () => {
  const { position } = useMap();
  const [geojsonData, setGeojsonData] = useState<any>(null);
  const [geoUnits, setGeoUnits] = useState(null);
  const [geoPois, setGeoPois] = useState(null);

  const handleLoadGeoJSON = useCallback((data: any) => {
    const updatedData = data.features.map((item: any, index: number) => {
      if (!Object.keys(item).includes('id')) {
        return {
          ...item,
          id: index,
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    const decoratedData = { ...data, features: updatedData };
    setGeojsonData(decoratedData);
  }, []);

  const handleLoadUnits = (data: any) => {
    const updatedData = data.features.map((item: any, index: number) => {
      if (!Object.keys(item).includes('id')) {
        return {
          ...item,
          id: index,
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    const decoratedData = { ...data, features: updatedData };
    setGeoUnits(decoratedData);
  };

  const handleLoadPois = (data: any) => {
    const updatedData = data.features.map((item: any, index: number) => {
      if (!Object.keys(item).includes('id')) {
        return {
          ...item,
          id: index,
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    const decoratedData = { ...data, features: updatedData };
    setGeoPois(decoratedData);
  };

  const handleDownloadGeoJSON = () => {
    if (!geojsonData) {
      return;
    }

    const dataStr = JSON.stringify(geojsonData);
    const dataBlob = new Blob([dataStr], { type: 'application/json' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(dataBlob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'data.geojson';
    link.click();
  };
  const handleDataChange = (data: any) => {
    setGeojsonData(data);
  };

  const handleGeometryChangeOnDraw = (data: any) => {
      // TODO: TO be implemented
  };

  const renderUnitLayer = () => {
    if (!geoUnits) {
      return null;
    }
    return <GeoJSONUnitLayer data={geoUnits} />;
  };


  return (
    <>
      <MenuOverlay
        onLoadGeoJSON={handleLoadGeoJSON}
        onDownloadGeoJSON={handleDownloadGeoJSON}
        onLoadUnits={handleLoadUnits}
        onLoadPois={handleLoadPois}
      />
      <div>
        <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true} style={{ minHeight: '87vh' }}>
          <Drawing handleGeometryUpdate={handleGeometryChangeOnDraw} />
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <MarkerClusterGroup disableClusteringAtZoom={16} chunkedLoading={true}>
            {renderUnitLayer()}
          </MarkerClusterGroup>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

This component is responsible for rendering the data present in geoUnits and the click is handled in the `onEachFeature`. The issue is that Marker component is rendered here, it creates an additional point which is then clustered and the new point has the properties of the point that is clicked.

GeoJSONUnitLayer.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GeoJSON, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';

interface GeoJSONUnitLayerProps {
  data: any;
}

const GeoJSONUnitLayer: React.FC<GeoJSONUnitLayerProps> = ({ data }) => {
  const map = useMap();
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState<any>([]);
  const [currentProperties, setCurrentProperties] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Center the map on the loaded GeoJSON data
    if (data) {
      const bounds = new L.GeoJSON(data).getBounds();
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }, [data, map]);

  const onEachFeature = (feature: any, layer: any) => {
    layer.on({
      click: (event: any) => {
        console.log('Clicked a point');
        setCurrentPosition([event.latlng.lat, event.latlng.lng]);
        setCurrentProperties(layer.feature.properties);
      },
    });
  };

  // Function to create a red icon for the points
  const redIcon = () =>
    new L.Icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
      iconSize: [25, 41],
      iconAnchor: [12, 41],
      popupAnchor: [1, -34],
      tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
    });

  const geoJSONStyle = {
    pointToLayer: (feature: any, latlng: L.LatLng) => {
      return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: redIcon(), // Use the custom red icon for each point
        riseOnHover: true,
      });
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data && <GeoJSON key="geojson-unit-layer" data={data} {...geoJSONStyle} />}
      {/* it looks like it creates a new point and then adds the marker to that point */}
      {currentPosition?.length ? (
        <Marker position={currentPosition}>
          <Popup>
            {currentProperties && (
              <div>
                <p>id: {currentProperties.id}</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default GeoJSONUnitLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The popup need to be created when the point is been created in the onEachFeature

```
const onEachFeature = (feature: any, layer: any) => {
    layer.bindPopup('<p>' + feature.properties.id + '</p>');
  };
```